# iOS swift language switcher

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I would like to have a language switcher in my storyBoard. I have two .strings files (localization files). how can i reload the the storyboard using the second .string file upon clicking the language switcher button?

[image]

Comment: You don't. The language is substituted in at runtime based on the translations added and the language set on the device. You can run the app with a different language to see what it would look like. What are you actually trying to do? Why do you want to switch the storyboard at design time? Essentially, because you are using Base localisation the storyboard has **no language** associated with it.

Comment: @Fogmeister, I am not asking for how to switch at design time. I need to do it at running time (exactly as if you are browsing a bi-lingual website, and switch the interface language) this is what i am looking for.

Comment: Oh, well it goes off the language of the device. You can either change your device or go to "Manage Schemes" in Xcode and select the language that you want to run the app in. You can't just switch it in the app though. Needs to be a device thing.

Comment: +1 with Fogmeister, this is not possible right out of the Box in iOS. You would have to implement your own system.

Comment: Echoing everyone else here: this is unexpected behavior for an app, and not something that should really be done. The web is different.